# How to configure postgresql so it accepts login+password auth?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have a fresh ubuntu 10.10 install with all updates and postgresql 8.4
In order for postgresql to accept login+password connections i have configured it via:

```
sudo su postgres
psql
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'password';
CREATE DATABASE myapp;
\q
exit
sudo vi /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf
change "local all all indent" to "local all all trust"
```

But, surprisingly, this is not working! The command

```
psql -U postgres password
```

Evaluates with error:

```
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Any hints how i can make the `psql -U` to work?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It is probably a good idea to leave the "postgres" user with ident authentication. By default I believe Ubuntu uses the "postgres" user to perform upgrades, backups, etc, and that requires that it is able to login without a specified password.

I recommend creating another user (probably with your own username) and giving it admin privileges as well. Then you can use that user with passwords on local connections.

Here is what the relevant parts of my pg_hba.conf look like:

```
# allow postgres user to use "ident" authentication on Unix sockets
# (as per recent comments, omit "sameuser" if on postgres 8.4 or later)
local   all   postgres                         ident sameuser
# allow all other users to use "md5" authentication on Unix sockets
local   all   all                              md5
# for users connected via local IPv4 or IPv6 connections, always require md5
host    all   all        127.0.0.1/32          md5
host    all   all        ::1/128               md5
```

Also note that `psql -U postgres password` will not do what you want. The password should never be specified on the commandline. That will try to login as user "postgres" to a database named "password".

You should use `psql -U postgres myapp` instead. Postgres will automatically prompt you for a password, if it is configured properly to require one.

In case we want the password be filled-in automatically, [place it in $HOME/.pgpass file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6405162/248616)

Comment: What is the correct way to add new user with admin privileges?

Comment: Adding user with "CREATE USER puser WITH PASSWORD 'password'" and doing "psql -U puser" evaluates to error "psql: FATAL: database "puser" does not exist"

Comment: It is usually easier to use the `createuser` commandline utility instead of creating the user with SQL. It has options to make the user an admin. Also, if it is telling you the database does not exist, then the login was successful. By default, postgres tries to login to the user's "home" database, which would have the same name as the user. Either create a "puser" database, or try `psql -U puser myapp` to login to "myapp".

Comment: Also to make your new "puser" into an admin, you should be able to do: `ALTER USER puser WITH CREATEUSER CREATEDB`

Comment: As of postgresql 8.4, "ident sameuser" needs to be changed to "ident".

Answer (score 3):

I think your `pg_ident.conf` file is misconfigured. Also, have you tried

```
psql -U postgres -W
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that can cause this is expired credentials.  I don't think this happened in version 8, but in version 9 when you create a new role in pgadmin, it is created in an expired state and you need to change or clear the role's expiration date before you will be able to login with it.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it helpful to create the database's user and schema in PostgreSQL:

1. Log into PostgreSQL from the `postgres` user

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

2. Once in, create the user and database

```
CREATE ROLE myuser LOGIN PASSWORD 'mypass';
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase WITH OWNER = myuser;
```

3. Log into PostgreSQL from the new user account

```
$ psql -h localhost -d mydatabase -U myuser -p <port>
```