# How do I specify a password to 'psql' non-interactively?

Tags: postgresql, bash, command-line, psql

I am trying to automate database creation process with a shell script and one thing I've hit a road block with passing a password to [psql](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Database_administration).
Here is a bit of code from the shell script:

```
psql -U $DB_USER -h localhost -c"$DB_RECREATE_SQL"
```

How do I pass a password to `psql` in a non-interactive way?

Comment: You can use a connection url. Check this answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582552/postgres-connection-url.

Comment: @paulodiovani I will just add that this works with no other options - just psql <connection URL> Thank you.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/app-psql.html):

> It is also convenient to have a ~/.pgpass file to avoid regularly having to type in passwords. See [Section 30.13](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html) for more information.

...

> This file should contain lines of the following format:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

> The password field from the first line that matches the current connection parameters will be used.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of pgpass, but this doesn't solve the issue - I need a self-contained bash script to operate over the database, hence my question about passing info to psql via command line.

Comment: I think your only option is to set up a .pgpass file that your bash script has access to.  Or don't use passwords at all--you could set up another form of authentication, such as ident, or using SSL certificates.

Comment: Another option might be to use expect. But I really hate expect :)

Comment: See the comment below about PGPASSWORD.    Arguably not as secure since it can be sniffed by poking around in /proc I think, but it does work quite well.

Comment: Don't forget to remove group and other user permission to read, write, execute the .pgpass file! Run `chmod go-rwx .pgpass`

Answer (score 1145):

Set the PGPASSWORD environment variable inside the script before calling psql

```
PGPASSWORD=pass1234 psql -U MyUsername myDatabaseName
```

For reference, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html

---

**Edit**

Since Postgres 9.2 there is also the option to specify a [connection string or URI](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) that can contain the username **and** password.  Syntax is:

```
$ psql postgresql://[user[:password]@][host][:port][,...][/dbname][?param1=value1&...]
```

Using that is a security risk because the password is visible in plain text when looking at the command line of a running process e.g. using `ps` (Linux), ProcessExplorer (Windows) or similar tools, by other users.

See also this question on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/14740/1822)

Comment: For example in one line you can do something like: 

PGPASSWORD=pass1234 psql -u MyUsername myUserName

Comment: I think that this is the most convenient way for simply running an SQL script.

Comment: I can only add - add a `space` in the command line before the first character and the command won't be stored in bash history. Works for ubuntu/bash.

Comment: BONUS: Works for Docker: `docker run -e PGPASSWORD="$(pbpaste)" --rm postgres psql -h www.example.com dbname username -c 'SELECT * FROM table;'`

Comment: Be careful and *make sure to always add a preceding space* otherwise it'll show up in your bash history ~/.bash_history file...

Comment: For those about to use this, be aware that including a password as part of a shell command will **1)** display it in the process list visible by *all* users of the system (e.g. `ps -ef`), and **2)** will add it to your shell's history file (e.g. `.bash_history`). My recommendation is to store the password in a safe file (e.g. use OS-level permissions to restrict access) and then `PGPASSWORD=$(cat /<path>/to/secret.txt) ...`.

Comment: Also, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: At least with bash this formulation fails. Check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28959903/2066215) instead.

Comment: Welcome fellow time travellers & thank you for your service here on SO. A quick warning from this mid-2021 visitor to honour the 10-year anniversary of this question: *On Fedora 32+ the old magic of putting a space before a command to hide it from history no longer works.* Even if "it works on my machine" today, you may be one OS update or malicious config change away from your secret being dumped into your bash history (and it was always leaked in `ps`). I will stick to the accepted answer or @code_dredd's useful alternative in a comment above, those feel like safer practices.

Comment: And obviously, check your .bashrc file for preceding space works!
`cat ~/.bashrc | grep HISTCONTROL`
It should be "=ignorespace" or ="ignoreboth" to ignore commands with preceding spaces or duplicated history

Comment: but it doesn't work if user `MyUsername` already has a password. is there a way of setting PGPASSWORD in that case?

Comment: You can put the password in an OS environment variable when you provision the machine-- then it is just available as a variable with the associated restrictions of how the CLI shell is initiated.

Answer (score 164):

- in one line:

  ```
  export PGPASSWORD='password'; psql -h 'server name' -U 'user name' -d 'base name' -c 'command'
  ```

  with *command*  a sql command such as `"select * from schema.table"`
- or more readable:

  ```
  export PGPASSWORD='password'
  psql -h 'server name' -U 'user name' -d 'base name' \
       -c 'command' (eg. "select * from schema.table")
  ```

Comment: The one line can be slightly simplified to:  `PGPASSWORD='password'  psql ....`  which also has the benefit of the variable not being accessible after the command is done.

Comment: `export PGPASSWORD=YourNewPassword` worked for me over other variations.

Comment: `export PGPASSWORD` sounds like a really bad idea

Comment: This will save the password in your bash history ~/.bash_history file (unless you carefully always add a preceding space), and also export the password to your current environment FWIW :|

Comment: There's no need to export `PGPASSWORD`.

Comment: on my case it worked, specifying also the `-w` flag.

Comment: ey Lads, i guess that the magic things is this => https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Bash.27s_quick_assignment_and_inheritance_trick. It seems it hasn't an oficial name... yet....

Answer (score 124):

I tend to prefer passing a URL to [psql](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Database_administration):

```
psql "postgresql://$DB_USER:$DB_PWD@$DB_SERVER/$DB_NAME"
```

This gives me the freedom to name my environment variables as I wish and avoids creating unnecessary files.

This requires `libpq`. The documentation can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING).

Comment: can you use something like this with pg_restore? Thanks!

Comment: @ccalderon911217 Apparently you can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28359470/1388292

Comment: @JacquesGaudin yep tested myself! Thank you!

Comment: This way the password will be visible to all users on your machine while the psql process is running. The complete command line (including the resolved content of the variable $DB_PWD) shows in "ps -ef" or "ps aux" commands. Therefore NOT RECOMMENDED AT ALL.

Answer (score 53):

On Windows:

1. Assign value to PGPASSWORD: `C:\>set PGPASSWORD=pass`
2. Run command: `C:\>psql -d database -U user`

Ready

Or in one line,

```
set PGPASSWORD=pass&& psql -d database -U user
```

Note the lack of space before the && !

Comment: I tried that, and it did not work. Still being asked for a password.

Comment: @antipattern You must pass option `-w` also.

Comment: `PGPASSWORD=xxxx psql -U username -d database -w -c "select * from foo;"` works.

Comment: In Powershell, you can do this: `$env:PGPASSWORD=pass; psql -d database -U user`

Comment: +1000 for the comment about no space before the && :)

Comment: "Note the lack of space before the &&": ok, but why?

Answer (score 31):

This can be done by creating a `.pgpass` file in the home directory of the (Linux) User.
`.pgpass`  file format:

```
<databaseip>:<port>:<databasename>:<dbusername>:<password>
```

You can also use wild card `*` in place of details.

Say I wanted to run `tmp.sql` without prompting for a password.

With the following code you can in *.sh file

```
echo "192.168.1.1:*:*:postgres:postgrespwd" > $HOME/.pgpass
echo "` chmod 0600 $HOME/.pgpass `"

echo " ` psql -h 192.168.1.1 -p 5432  -U postgres  postgres  -f tmp.sql `
```

Comment: What's the point of echo "` chmod 0600 $HOME/.pgpass `"? How about just chmod 0600 $HOME/.pgpass ?

Answer (score 31):

An alternative to using the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable is to use the `conninfo` string according to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-psql.html):

> An alternative way to specify connection parameters is in a conninfo
>   string or a URI, which is used instead of a database name. This
>   mechanism give you very wide control over the connection.

```
$ psql "host=<server> port=5432 dbname=<db> user=<user> password=<password>"

postgres=>
```

Comment: I often use this approach as it seems more readable, but for the sake of security, having the password in the command is not a brilliant idea, as it can be read with a simple `ps a` command by any (non-root) user

Answer (score 27):

If its not too late to add most of the options in one answer:

There are a couple of options:

1. set it in the pgpass file. [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html)

2. set an environment variable and get it from there:

   `export PGPASSWORD='password'`

   and then run your psql to login or even run the command from
   there:

   `psql -h clustername -U username -d testdb`
3. On windows you will have to use "set" :

   `set PGPASSWORD=pass` and then login to the psql bash.
4. Pass it via URL & env variable:

   `psql "postgresql://$USER_NAME:$PASSWORD@$HOST_NAME/$DB_NAME"`

Comment: Version 4 makes the content of the variable $PASSWORD visible to all sessions on the machine. Therefore STRONGLY DISCOURAGED.

Answer (score 24):

Just to add more clarity.

You can assign the password to the `PGPASSWORD` variable.

So instead of the below which will require you to type the password:

```
psql --host=aurora-postgres.cluster-fgshdjdf.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --user=my_master_user --password --dbname=postgres
```

We will replace the `--password` flag with `PGPASSWORD=QghyumjB3ZtCQkdf`. So it will be:

```
PGPASSWORD=QghyumjB3ZtCQkdf psql --host=aurora-postgres.cluster-fgshdjdf.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --user=my_master_user --dbname=postgres
```

This way you will not be required to type the password.

Answer (score 12):

Added content of pg_env.sh to my .bashrc:

```
cat /opt/PostgreSQL/10/pg_env.sh

#!/bin/sh
# The script sets environment variables helpful for PostgreSQL

export PATH=/opt/PostgreSQL/10/bin:$PATH
export PGDATA=/opt/PostgreSQL/10/data
export PGDATABASE=postgres
export PGUSER=postgres
export PGPORT=5433
export PGLOCALEDIR=/opt/PostgreSQL/10/share/locale
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/opt/PostgreSQL/10/share/man
```

with addition of (as per user4653174 suggestion)

```
export PGPASSWORD='password'
```

Comment: full reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html

Answer (score 6):

```
psql postgresql://myawsumuser:myPassword@127.0.0.1:5432/myawsumdb
```

Comment: This makes myPassword visible to all sessions on the machine. Therefore STRONGLY DISCOURAGED.

Answer (score 0):

Bash script for using in usual terminal:

```
echo $PASSWORD psql --host=$HOST --dbname=$DBNAME --username=$USER_NAME --command="$SQL_COMMAND"
```

If you have to connect to remote server by using openshift client you can use this:

```
oc rsh $POD echo $PASSWORD | oc rsh -c database $POD psql --host=$HOST --dbname=$DBNAME --username=$USER_NAME --command="$SQL_COMMAND"
```