# Run a PostgreSQL .sql file using command line arguments

Tags: postgresql, command-line, psql

I have some .sql files with thousands of INSERT statements in them and need to run these inserts on my PostgreSQL database in order to add them to a table. The files are that large that it is impossible to open them and copy the INSERT statements into an editor window and run them there. I found on the Internet that you can use the following by navigating to the bin folder of your PostgreSQL install:

```
psql -d myDataBase -a -f myInsertFile
```

In my case:

```
psql -d HIGHWAYS -a -f CLUSTER_1000M.sql
```

I am then asked for a password for my user, but I cannot enter anything and when I hit enter I get this error:

> psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myUsername"

Why won't it let me enter a password. Is there a way round this as it is critical that I can run these scripts?

I got around this issue by adding a new entry in my pg_hba.conf file with the following structure:

```
# IPv6 local connections:
host    myDbName    myUserName ::1/128    trust
```

The pg_hba.conf file can usually be found in the 'data' folder of your PostgreSQL install.

Comment: You've already had your answer but just in case... "I cannot enter anything", might you be talking about the fact that typing your password doesn't show anything? That's normal in this case, normally typing the password and hitting Enter *should* work...

Comment: I had a similar problem installing a copy of ITIS (http://itis.gov). The database didn't exist, so I couldn't use its name. Because of the way PostgreSQL works, I could do this: psql --port=5554 --username=root --file=ITIS.sql template1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify a password to 'psql' non-interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127/how-do-i-specify-a-password-to-psql-non-interactively)

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You have four choices to supply a password:

1. Set the PGPASSWORD environment variable. For details see the manual: 
   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html
2. Use a .pgpass file to store the password. For details see the manual: 
   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html
3. Use "trust authentication" for that specific user: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-TRUST
4. Since PostgreSQL 9.1 you can also [use a connection string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-CONNECTING): 
   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING

Comment: Hi. I have now set the settings to trust but I notice that the software is trying to use my windows username in order to login. I want to use a role that I have setup in my Postgresql database. Is there a way of telling it which role to use to run the command?

Comment: @CSharpened: use the `-u` parameter as documented in the manual

Comment: #2 is extremely simple. Just add one line containing host:port:db:user:pass to a file and you're done. Nice work.

Answer (score 733):

Of course, you will get a fatal error for authenticating, because you do not include a user name...

Try this one, it is OK for me :)

```
psql -U username -d myDataBase -a -f myInsertFile
```

If the database is remote, use the same command with host

```
psql -h host -U username -d myDataBase -a -f myInsertFile
```

Comment: Note that the provided username has to be a valid postgres role. The default is the currently logged in user.

Comment: Why the `-a` param?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka `-a` is not needed here. It's "Print all nonempty input lines to standard output as they are read"

Comment: Is it possible to specify an sql file that is stored at a url? For instance in an s3 bucket @ https://my-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/import.sql ?

Answer (score 464):

You should do it like this:

```
\i path_to_sql_file
```

See:

[image]

Comment: I get `Permission denied`

Comment: after doing `chmod 777 myfile` error `Permission denied` was fixed

Comment: @Zac if your Permission denied happened on a windows machine, you might be using the wrong slashes.

Comment: I had this error on windows and it turned out to be the slashes, as @pgsandstrom mentioned. Wrong slashes = use forward slashes instead, and no quote on path. \i c:/dev/script.sql

Comment: I am getting `No such file or directory` although the file path has been specified correctly.Any idea?

Answer (score 89):

If you are logged in into psql on the Linux shell the command is:

```
\i fileName.sql
```

for an absolute path and

```
\ir filename.sql
```

for the relative path from where you have called psql.

Comment: As @Florian says, once logged in you can execute a file. Remember to mark any comment lines in your SQL as either of two ways ...-- comment to end of line
a) -- one line comment   OR
b) /* multiple line comments */

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, it ran very well.

Answer (score 84):

Use this to execute *.sql files when the PostgreSQL server is located in a difference place:

```
psql -h localhost -d userstoreis -U admin -p 5432 -a -q -f /home/jobs/Desktop/resources/postgresql.sql

-h PostgreSQL server IP address
-d database name
-U user name
-p port which PostgreSQL server is listening on
-f path to SQL script
-a all echo
-q quiet 
-f file
```

Then you are prompted to enter the password of the user.

EDIT: updated based on the comment provided by @zwacky

Comment: @ChickenWing24 `-a`: all echo, `-q`: quiet, `-f`: file

Comment: does this work without database? I'm trying to create new database using this tool into existing server.

Comment: Not sure why someone removed the `-f` option. It is most certainly there.

Answer (score 56):

```
export PGPASSWORD=<password>
psql -h <host> -d <database> -U <user_name> -p <port> -a -w -f <file>.sql
```

Comment: how can I do that without output

Comment: psql -h <host> -d <database> -U <user_name> -p <port> -a -q -w -f  <file>.sql

Comment: @Lu32 You could also leave out the flag -a (which means "Print all nonempty input lines to standard output as they are read"). EDIT tested, without -a it prints out less, but still too much information. So the -q flag is correct, as vishu9219 said.

Answer (score 30):

Via the terminal log on to your database and try this:

```
database-# >@pathof_mysqlfile.sql
```

or

```
database-#>-i pathof_mysqlfile.sql
```

or

```
database-#>-c pathof_mysqlfile.sql
```

Comment: this solution is more solid as for me; not the one marked as answe

Comment: Is there any difference between `@`, `-i ` and `-c `?

Answer (score 28):

You can give both user name and PASSSWORD on the command line itself with the "-d" parameter

```
   psql -d "dbname='urDbName' user='yourUserName' password='yourPasswd' host='yourHost'" -f yourFileName.sql
```

Comment: This works if you don't want to set environment variables or use strange pass files. =)

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer, thank you

Comment: This is the right answer. thank you so much.

Answer (score 16):

you could even do it in this way:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d myDataBase -a -f myInsertFile
```

If you have `sudo` access on machine and it's not recommended for production scripts just for test on your own machine it's the easiest way.

Answer (score 15):

**2021 Solution**

if your PostgreSQL database is on your system locally.

```
psql dbname < sqldump.sql username
```

If its hosted online

```
psql -h hostname dbname < sqldump.sql username
```

If you have any doubts or questions, please ask them in the comments.

Comment: is it OS dependent?

Comment: @BingLi224 I use a Windows System and I'm pretty sure that it's not OS dependent.

Comment: Best answer. Applicable to Ubuntu/Debian systems. If you run it from a user with the permission to alter the database, you can even omit the `username` part, so it's just `psql dbname < sqldump.sql`.

Comment: @Neurotransmitter true, that will work as well.

Answer (score 13):

```
psql -h localhost -d userstoreis -U admin -p 5432 -a -q -f /home/jobs/Desktop/resources/postgresql.sql
```

Parameter explanations:

```
-h PostgreSQL server IP address
-d database name
-U user name
-p port which PostgreSQL server is listening on
-f path to SQL script
-a all echo
-q quiet
```

Comment: Thanks spent some time searching for a "-a" option

Answer (score 11):

**Walk through on how to run an SQL on the command line for PostgreSQL in Linux:**

Open a terminal and make sure you can run the `psql` command:

```
psql --version
which psql
```

Mine is version 9.1.6 located in `/bin/psql`.

Create a plain textfile called `mysqlfile.sql`

Edit that file, put a single line in there:

```
select * from mytable;
```

Run this command on commandline (substituting your username and the name of your database for pgadmin and kurz_prod):

```
psql -U pgadmin -d kurz_prod -a -f mysqlfile.sql
```

The following is the result I get on the terminal (I am not prompted for a password):

```
select * from mytable;

test1
--------
hi
me too

(2 rows)
```

Comment: How do you set up a user? It's my first time installing and running -f on a new .sql file. Always says wrong password

Answer (score 4):

You can open a command prompt and run as administrator. Then type

```
../bin>psql -f c:/...-h localhost -p 5432 -d databasename -U "postgres"
```

`Password for user postgres:` will show up.

Type your password and enter. I couldn't see the password what I was typing, but this time when I press enter it worked. Actually I was loading data into the database.

Comment: I think you mean `-d "postgres"`

Comment: @amphetamachine `-d `for  database name , check `psql --help`

Answer (score 2):

A small improvement in @wingman__7 's 2021 answer: if your username contains certain characters (an underscore in my case), you need to pass it with the `-U` flag.
This worked for me:

```
$ psql -h db.host -d db_name -U my_user < query.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following command in the command line console:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -f restore.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

I achived that wrote (located in the directory where my script is)

```
::someguy@host::$sudo -u user psql -d my_database -a -f file.sql
```

where `-u user`  is the role who owns the database where I want to execute the script then the `psql` connects to the `psql` console after that `-d my_database` loads me in `mydatabase` finally `-a -f file.sql` where `-a` echo all input from the script and `-f` execute commands from `file.sql` into `mydatabase`, then exit.

I'm using:
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.12 
on (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -u postgres -i .
```

postgres is username who you use to install postgres

```
psql -d demo -a -f demo.sql
```

demo -is name db

demo.sql file sql backup

Answer (score 0):

The following is my preferred method as well as how to save the results to a txt file:

```
export PGPASSWORD='your_password'
psql -U postgres -h localhost -d mydatabase -a -f /path/to/your/sqlfile.sql -o /path/to/your/output.txt
```