# Connect with psql from remote machine to remote postgres database with saved password

Tags: postgresql, unix, psql

I am working on a remote Unix machine where I connect via SSH from my local machine. There is a Postgres database on another host that I need to connect from my remote machine using psql.

I would like to be able to run queries from an input file and save the results to an output file, however I did not manage to automatically set the password, surpassing the need to do it every time I run a query.

I tried the following:

1. Run

   ```
   psql "user=username password=password host=hostname port=port dbname=database"`
   ```

   with my `username`, `password`, `hostname`, `port` and `database` values.
   This worked OK but I did not find a way to add arguments for input/output files (not needing to go through Postgres interactive environment).
2. According to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736085/run-a-postgresql-sql-file-using-command-line-args), I created a file `~/.pgpass` with the following format: `hostname:port:database:username:password`

   and then `chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass` but when connecting as: `psql -h hostname -U username -d database -w` psql ignored this (I got the following failed authentication message.)

   > psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied.

   Note that my remote machine's name is different than my username, so this might also create a problem when creating the `.pgpass` file. Is there any other way to do it?

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the name of your remote machine have to do with your username? By the way, you didn't specify the port in your second `psql` invocation, but I doubt that matters in this context.

Comment: Well, according to this [http://serverfault.com/questions/526170/psql-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied], it might make a difference. I tried specifying the port as well but as you said this is not the problem.

Comment: This question is about using `sudo` to call `psql`. Are you using `sudo` to call `psql`?

Comment: No, apologies for this. I cannot use sudo since it is a remote machine. I want to create a bash script that takes two arguments (input/output files) and runs the query automatically using psql.

Comment: I managed to find a solution to what I wanted in this SO question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523019/postgresql-scripting-psql-execution-with-password], I did search enough before posting but I needed to rephrase my question I guess. The solution is to write `PGPASSWORD=password psql -h hostname -U username -d database -f inputfile -o outputfile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This worked OK but I did not find a way to add arguments for
>   input/output files

You can either redirect the input file to psql, or specify it in `-f` option:

```
psql < input.sql
psql -f input.sql
```

As for output file, just redirect psql's output to it:

```
psql -f input.sql > output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. This did not work using the psql string mode. The solution was to add PGPASSWORD=password before psql and then do as you write.

Comment: Why not? `psql "host=... dbname=... user=... port=... password=..." < input.sql > output.sql` works fine.

Comment: I did not try this, I tried to use -f -o arguments and it did not work, thank you