# Run Postgres File from Command Line (Without actually printing out code)

Tags: macos, postgresql

I can successfully run SQL (Postgres) files from command line following instructions here:

[Run a PostgreSQL .sql file using command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736085/run-a-postgresql-sql-file-using-command-line-args)

In particular, I use something like

```
psql -d DBPASSWORD -a -f FILENAME
```

Problem is that this (and specifically, I believe the `-a`) prints the sql code out to the terminal. This is annoying because I am running a lot of files in sequence within a Python script using `subprocess`, and I would rather not have the SQL code print out in terminal. Is there a way to not print the SQL code out to terminal?

EDIT: I've tried adding the `-q` option like people said, but the code in the SQL file is still being printed out to terminal.

What I tried was

```
psql -q -d DBPASSWORD -a -f FILENAME 
psql -d DBPASSWORD -q -a -f FILENAME 
psql -d DBPASSWORD -a -q -f FILENAME 
psql -d DBPASSWORD -a -f FILENAME -q
```

And in each of those cases, the code in `FILENAME` is being printed to terminal

Comment: What OS are you running? If it is some kind of UNIX you can redirect output to /dev/null like 'psql -d foo > /dev/null'.

Comment: `--quiet` or `-q` should do it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html

Comment: maybe the -q / -quiet option?

Comment: @Vincent That'll fall into the category. :-) But maybe -q is better as others have suggested.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work? I've tried

`psql -q -d DBPASSWORD -a -f FILENAME`
`psql -d DBPASSWORD  -q -a -f FILENAME`
`psql -d DBPASSWORD -a  -q -f FILENAME`
`psql -d DBPASSWORD -a  -f FILENAME -q`

to no avail.

Comment: What exactly is "not working". What kind of output do you still get? What is the content of the file? Please [edit] your question and provide that information. Do not post code in comments.

Comment: Then try to redirect to/dev/null as I suggested.

Comment: `-a` or `--echo-all` option [Print all nonempty input lines to standard output as they are read.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) So what is your actual goal?

Comment: My goal is to the a SQL query from command line where I just have to specify the filename and I don't want to print the code to terminal.

Comment: So just remove the `-a` option.

Comment: Oh great! I think that works.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to redirect `STDOUT`, `STDERR` or both to a log file.

Something like one of these

- `psql ... > out.log`
- `psql ... 2> err.log`
- `psql ... &> out_and_err.log`

Comment: Interesting. So if I run `psql -d DBPASSWORD -f FILENAME -q &> out_and_err.log` that will redirect both `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to a log file?

Comment: Exactly, you don't even need the `-q` option to get the full details in the log file. You can also combine `>` and `2>` to have errors in one file and regular output in another file.

Comment: `psql -d DBPASSWORD -f FILENAME -q &> out_and_err.log` gave the error TypeError: bufsize must be an integer