# Postgres EDB Run a sequence of sql files

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to run a sequence of SQL files using PEM. From the Oracle database I used:

```
@path_to_file1.sql
@path_to_file2.sql
@path_to_file3.sql
```

How do I do this using Postgres Enterprise Manager (PEM) ?

Please note that i'm **NOT USING** a command line and I don't want to run a **SINGLE** file, but I'm using PEM on a windows machine to run a **SEQUENCE** of sql files in one shot.

Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a postgresql .sql file using command line args](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736085/run-a-postgresql-sql-file-using-command-line-args)

Comment: I'm not using a command line to run a single file. I'm using PEM and a "sequence of files". I'm using a windows machine.