# How to create a script that automatically creates a PSQL database locally?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a React/Node.js project, in which I want to have a local database for development purposes.

I have the SQL code to create and populate tables in a file called `db-setup.sql`.

How would I go about creating a script that would initialize a database in PostgreSQL and create the tables based on the queries in the `db-setup.sql` file? I assume more things have to be initialized, but am unsure where to start.

I am new to writing such scripts, so any help is welcome!

Comment: I would look into [creating a stored procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html) and then you could just simply make one call to that procedure from your preferred language.

Comment: Granted, the learning curve on creating stored procedures a a little steep, but you will thank yourself in the long run if you master them.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to learn stored procedures for this. Postgresql can execute .sql files via CLI: [Run a PostgreSQL .sql file using command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736085/run-a-postgresql-sql-file-using-command-line-arguments)