# DROP Postgres SCHEMA or TABLE using Windows Batch File

Tags: postgresql, schema, pgadmin, drop

1. I want to perform DROP and CREATE SCHEMA in PostgreSQL using **Batch file**. I have PostgresSQL installed on many machines without any interface like PgAdmin.
2. I am looking for a simple solution to let Technicians perform resetting of database and restore the default backup at production site. Batch file seems to be a good solution.
3. I already figure out command to restore backup using Batch file. The missing item is the drop/create SCHEMA (As i need to create new SCHEMA before restoring the default back up).
4. I tried following command to DROP / CREATE SCHEMA. However it only works when used via PgAdmin or if i type manually under **postgres=#** prompt on CMD.

```
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA public;

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO public;
```

5. Using the above code in batch file generates following Error.

> **'drop' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

Any suggestions, please let me know. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You should pass your commands to a data base. Not sure how to do this on Windows, on linux you can use `psql {commands here}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the statements you want to run into a (text) file e.g. `drop.sql`

Then in your batch file use:

```
psql -U <your_username_here> -d <your_database_here> -f drop.sql
```

`psql` will prompt you for a password, see [Run a PostgreSQL .sql file using command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736085) for possible options to overcome that.