# Execute 50k insert queries in postgresql dbeaver

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any possibility to insert 50k datasets into a postgresql database using dbeaver?
Locally, it worked fine for me, it took me 1 minute, because I also changed the memory settings of postgresql and dbeaver. But for our development environment, 50k queries did not work.

Is there a way to do this anyway or do I need to split the queries and do for example 10k queries 5 times? Any trick?

EDIT: with "did not work" I mean I got an error after 2500 seconds saying something like "too much data ranges"

Comment: Can't you use the COPY statement? That's way faster than INSERT

Comment: "50k queries did not work": please describe what happened.

Comment: Use `copy` instead pf `insert` statements. If not possible, split your inserts in small batches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to execute a giant script sql via interface: don't even try.

If you have a csv file, DBeaver gives you a tool:

[image: DBeaver import tool]

Even better, as described in comments, copy command is the tool.

If you have a giant SQL file you need to use command line, like:

```
psql -h host -U username -d myDataBase -a -f myInsertFile
```

Like in this post: [Run a PostgreSQL .sql file using command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736085/run-a-postgresql-sql-file-using-command-line-arguments)

Comment: hi, thanks, but can you elaborate a bit more please, what you mean with command line? doing it via windows command line?

Comment: Done! You should have tools installed.