# postgres pg_restore pbl with windows shell mode

Tags: windows, postgresql, cmd

The following

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.14\pg_restore.exe"  --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --password "postgres" --dbname "base_nationale"  --verbose "E:\dump\ff_d01_2011.dump"`

gives this error message:

> pg_restore: too many command-line arguments (first is "--host"

why it doesn't fuctionne?

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify a value for `--password`. That switch only forces a password *prompt* and should actually never be needed.

Just remove the part `--password "postgres"`. If a password is needed, `pg_restore` will automatically prompt you for it.

If you want to run that command without a password prompt, you need a `.pgpass` file or use the environment variable `PGPASS`

Details are in the manual:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Or this SO question: [How do I specify a password to psql non-interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6405127/330315)