# In pg_restore, how can you use a postgres connection string to specify the host/database/username/password?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

When using pg_dump, you can use a postgres connection string to specify the host/database/username/password:

```
pg_dump postgres://someuser:somepassword@somehost.com:5432/somedatabase
```

I want to use the same sort of connection string for pg_restore:

```
pg_restore -f dump.dump postgres://userb:somepassword@somehost.com:5432/otherdatabase
```

But I get an error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] could not open input file "postgres://userb:somepassword@somehost.com:5432/otherdatabase": No such file or directory
```

Comment: The [manual is clear](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) about the flags you should use.

Comment: The manual says:
pg_restore [connection-option...] [option...] [filename]
when i try:
pg-restore postgres://userb:somepassword@somehost.com:5432/otherdatabase -f dump.dump 
I get the same error

Comment: and why do you think *[connection-options]* can accept a full connection url? This is not what the manual says.

Comment: It accepts a full connection url for pg_dump  - even though the manual for [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html) does not mention being able to use a full connection url

Comment: I see, but if i get it right, `pg_dump` accepts it as its `dbname` parameter. That is the `-d` option with `pg_restore`. Parameter(s) without option are used as input `filename` (with `pg_restore`), that's for sure.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

In PostgreSQL tools wherever you can specify a database name you can instead specify a connection string.

In the syntax for `pg_restore` the dbname is passed with a flag, not as a positional parameter:

```
$ pg_restore --help
pg_restore restores a PostgreSQL database from an archive created by pg_dump.

Usage:
  pg_restore [OPTION]... [FILE]

General options:
  -d, --dbname=NAME        connect to database name
  ...
```

so you should be using:

```
pg_restore -d 'postgres://userb:somepassword@somehost.com:5432/otherdatabase' dump.dump
```

Yes, that user interface mismatch between `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` sucks, and I wish we could change it, but it's a bit late now.

Comment: Avoiding `''` worked for me. 
The command in my case is 
`pg_restore -d postgresql://userb:somepassword@somehost.com:5432/otherdatabase D:\DBbackup\backup.dump`

Comment: @ManojRawat That's because you're using Windows, which has different rules for command-line argument quoting. The `'...'` is parsed by the shell (bash or zsh usually) then the bare argument is passed to `pg_dump`. On Windows, instead the whole string is passed to `pg_dump` which must parse it itself.