# Run psql and pg_dump without password and without using sudo -u postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to copy one table from one database to another:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump -t _stats db30 | psql db8;
```

However, I always get asked for a password, and I do not know what it is. Is there a way to do this without pg_dump? Is there a way so that I can not be asked for a password when I run `psql`?

Note, to get into postgres I have to run `sudo -u postgres psql` instead of psql

Comment: Why do you *have* to use `sudo`. Can't you just use `psql -U postgres`?  For providing a password see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6405127/330315 (but that would need to be done as the linux user `postgres`, not the one you are working with)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

User management and permission on a postgres server is a complex topic, but you have probably only a server installed on your desktop and use it only on localhost, so security is not so important.

You have to do 3 steps:

1) Edit the pg_hba.conf file and restart the server

2) Login with psql and set a password for the user `postgres`

3) Edit (or create) the file ~/.pgpass

NOTE: you could use the authentication method `trust` in pg_hba.conf and avoid the step 2 and 3, but this is really **TOO** permissive, and you shouldn't use it, even on localhost.

**The pg_hba.conf file**

To understand the file pg_hba.conf please read here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Basically, if you server is on localhost and security does not matter, you can simply allow all user to connect with `md5` authentication method. 
If you don't know, where this file is, use this command:

```
locate pg_hba.conf
```

Probably is in `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf` or similar.

Edit the file and change the already existing lines so (at end of the file):

```
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

Now restart the server with

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

**Set a password for the user postgres**

First login in psql:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Now, within psql, change the password:

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'your-password';
```

**The pgpass file**

Now you can login in psql with `psql -U postgres` (without `sudo -u postgres`) but have to enter the password. To avoid to digit the password every time,  you can set up the pgpass file. If does not already exist, you must create a file named `.pgpass` in your home directory. The file must be owned by your user and be readable only by your user:

```
chown $USER:$USER ~/.pgpass
chmod 600 ~/.pgpass
```

Now write in the file those lines:

```
localhost:5432:*:postgres:your-password
127.0.0.1:5432:*:postgres:your-password
```

Alternately you can use the environment variable `PGPASSWORD`:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-envars.html

Ready. Now you can login in postgres with `psql -U postgres` without enter the password.

Comment: it says password authentication failed for user "root", even when I changed the password it doesn't work

Comment: simply run `psql -U postgres`, without sudo

Comment: my userName is rahul so will this command is like `chown $rahul:$rahul ~/.pgpass`? beacause it's still asking for the password , I have kept .pgpass and my databasedumpscript.pyfile on same path.

Comment: don't use $rahul, this is wrong. Simply use $USER, like explained in the answer