# psql Loop through folder of CSVs to Copy to AWS RDS Postgres Table

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, psql

I am trying to use a `psql` loop to load a directory of csv files into an AWS RDS Postgres database.

[This StackExchange post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136182/load-multi-csv-files-from-local-disc-to-postgres) answers how to do so locally and the following code works with a single file:

`PGPASSWORD='MyPassword' psql -h my-rds.instance.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U user -d mydatabase -c '\COPY dbo.input_table FROM ''MySingleFile.csv'' CSV HEADER'`

but I can't "combine" the two features. This code is the closest I can get but I get the following error for each file that is identified by the `ls *.csv` command:

```
for x in $(ls *.csv); 
do PGPASSWORD='MyPassword' psql -h my-rds.instance.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U user -d mydatabase -c "\COPY dbo.input_table FROM ''MySingleFile.csv'' CSV HEADER"; done

ERROR:  conflicting or redundant options
...
ERROR:  conflicting or redundant options
```

Comment: something like `for filename in *.csv  ; do` ? and then `dostuff $filename`

Comment: sorry but no, same error message

Comment: Strange. I have loop here working like this `for filename in *.xml*  ; do
    for ((i=0; i<=3; i++)); do   
        perl -i -pe 's/\n/\\n/g' $filename 
    done
done`

Comment: Ya, sorry, not sure what's different about my code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax you used in the command inside the loop. In case the loop isn't the issue, consider removing this `PGPASSWORD='MyPassword'` and placing a password inside the `.pgpass` file. Good luck man! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127/how-do-i-specify-a-password-to-psql-non-interactively