# postgres periodical auto dump

Tags: bash, postgresql

I would like to dump postgres database and make it periodical with crontab.

so I tried to run the following in a bash script:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://django:mypass@127.0.0.1:5432/django
```

I get this:

> -bash: !: event not found

probably because there are special characters in the password. how to escape from special characters? how can I pass the password parameter? is there any other way to auto dump periodically from postgresql.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6405127/330315

Comment: Yes, the better option is to use a .pgpass file instead, otherwise the password will be visible when you list processes with `ps aux`

Answer (score 0):

You must [encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the special characters.

If your password is `a!b@c` , the command would be

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://django:a%21b%40c@127.0.0.1:5432/django
```