# psql dropping slashes in file path

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to execute this

```
psql "user=postgres password=xxxx hostaddr=xxxx port=5432 dbname=xxx options='-f D:\scripts2\201804130713_test.sql'"
```

programmatically in order to run a change script on my database.

I am following the answer here that has 305 up-votes. [How do I specify a password to psql non-interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127/how-do-i-specify-a-password-to-psql-non-interactively) for using the connection string.

The connection string works, but the file argument has all the slashes removed from the path. I don't know how to escape them, and various things I have tried has introduced problems with single quotes, etc. I think my approach may be off by quite bit. I just need a way to do this.

Comment: Don't know much about Windows, but did you try replacing \ with \\?

Comment: I  tried that and it didn't help. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

`options` in a connection string is for server-side parameters, not for psql command-line switches.

> options
>
> Specifies command-line options to send to the server at connection start. For example, setting this to -c geqo=off sets the session's
>   value of the geqo parameter to off. Spaces within this string are
>   considered to separate command-line arguments, unless escaped with a
>   backslash (); write \ to represent a literal backslash. For a
>   detailed discussion of the available options, consult Chapter 19.

You probably want:

```
psql -f D:\scripts2\201804130713_test.sql "user=postgres password=xxxx hostaddr=xxxx port=5432 dbname=xxx"
```

Comment: I tried it and it strips off the slashes. I also tried wrapping it in single quotes and it reverses the slashes, and it does the same thing if I escape the slashes.

Comment: I found a way around it and just went back to regular command-line arguments following a set PGPassword=. Not the way I wanted to do it, but it works.