# PostgreSQL Table export automation

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to export the table overnight using the Windows Task scheduler, if i manually login to command prompt and execute the below three commands one-by-one it works fine. csv file will be created on the destination directory. If I try to create a bat script and try to execute the same, it stops after executing first line(i need to manually type the second line), is there a way to automate it please?

```
psql -U nrgadmin -d enwdb
\copy nrgcore.bookmarks to 'D:\Bookmarks_Table\Bookmarks.csv' csv;
\q
```

Comment: `psql -U nrgadmin -d enwdb -c "COPY nrgcore.bookmarks TO 'D:\Bookmarks_Table\Bookmarks.csv' CSV"`

Comment: It's probably asking for a password: see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127

Comment: Thank you @eurotrash, your solution worked fine. Thanks very much.