# Call pg_restore from python

Tags: python, pg-restore

I'm trying to automatically download pg_dump files and restore these. I'm having trouble executing the `pg_restore` command. I'm currently using:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import shlex


command = f'pg_restore ' \
          f'-h {host} ' \
          f'-d {database} ' \
          f'-U {username} ' \
          f'{file_path}'

command = shlex.split(command)
p = Popen(command, shell=False, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p.communicate(str.encode(f'\r{password}\r'))
```

This however prompts me to fill in my password (when I fill it in, it works just fine).

What I've tried so far:

- set `shell = True` (in which case I get the error `[Info]     2019-12-09 14:59:55 - [root] (b'', b'pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive (too short?)\n')`)
- pass the password using

`p.stdin.write(f'{self.push_password}\n')`
`p.stdin.flush()`

- Using `\n` instead of `\r`
- Only passing `\r` at the end of the `p.communicate`

I'm out of ideas and don't know what to do. Does anybody know how to automatically pass my password when calling pg_restore from python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways.

**Set environmental variables:**

```
PGDATABASE, PGHOST, PGPORT and/or PGUSER
```

**Set in file**

Password can be put in a file and postgresql picks it up

**Documention**

When the defaults aren't quite right, you can save yourself some typing by setting the environment variables PGDATABASE, PGHOST, PGPORT and/or PGUSER to appropriate values. (For additional environment variables, see Section 30.12.) It is also convenient to have a ~/.pgpass file to avoid regularly having to type in passwords. See Section 30.13 for more information.

More: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/app-psql.html

Discussed here: [How do I specify a password to psql non-interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127/how-do-i-specify-a-password-to-psql-non-interactively)