# Restoring Postgres database fails: password authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql

I tried to restore a Postgres database like this:

```
cat backup.sql | docker run -i postgres:12 /usr/bin/psql \
  -h mydb.elephantsql.com -U mydbanduser mydbanduser
```

This is the output:

```
Password for user mydbanduser:
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "mydbanduser"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "mydbanduser"
```

As can be seen, the password prompt is shown but it just steps over so I can't enter a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it for me:

```
cat backup.sql | docker run -e PGPASSWORD=mypassword -i postgres:12 /usr/bin/psql \
  -h mydb.elephantsql.com -U mydbanduser -d mydbanduser
```

Comment: Typing password into shell is [considered vulnerable since it potentially reveals password in shell history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6405296/653539). I would recommend to OP to prefer Laurenz's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [password file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) in the home directory of the user that runs `psql`:

> The file `.pgpass` in a user's home directory can contain passwords to be used if the connection requires a password (and no password has been specified otherwise). On Microsoft Windows the file is named `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` (where `%APPDATA%` refers to the Application Data subdirectory in the user's profile). Alternatively, a password file can be specified using the connection parameter [`passfile`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-PASSFILE) or the environment variable `PGPASSFILE`.
>
> This file should contain lines of the following format:
>
> `hostname:port:database:username:password`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was using docker-compose and python's dotenv to pass the PGPASSWORD variable.  My password has special characters in it. This caused me issues in macOS

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123#ABC
```

I was putting in the above, and having everything after `123` truncated due to the pound sign.

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=`123#ABC`
```

Single quotes fixed my issue.