# Popen does not take input from proc.communicate how to execute function that asks for a password with python?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, popen, proc

```
        text="odoo15"
        message=text.encode()
        

        proc = Popen(["psql",
        "-h","localhost",
        "-d", "database", 
        "-U", "User", 
        "-f", "/path/dump.sql"], stdin=PIPE)

        proc.communicate(input=message)
```

Before I execute that code I am connected with the database using psycopg. I want to execute sql code from a file onto a database to create tables and fill them with data coming from the dumb file. The trouble I have is that I still need to manually enter the password in the console for this code to work. I do not understand why it is not taking the password from proc.communicate. I would be really grateful for some help.

I also tried it with subprocess.run and having input as an argument but had the same problem. My first idea was to use the /i command from psql but since I cannot execute psql in psycopg it did not work. I also tried:
`cursor.execute(open("/path/dump.sql", "r").read())`
and
 `os.system("sudo -u user  psql database < /path/dump.sql")`  but the first could not execute because i have \ in my file and the second did also not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify a password to 'psql' non-interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127/how-do-i-specify-a-password-to-psql-non-interactively)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid all of this, you can directly set the [`PGPASSWORD`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) env var. When doing this, the CLI won't ask for the password.

You can do this in multiple ways:

1. `export PGPASSWORD=yourpassword`
2. `proc = Popen(["PGPASSWORD=yourpassword", "psql",...`
3. `PGPASSWORD=yourpassword python yourscript.py`
4. Inside your python script, `import os; os.environ["PGPASSWORD"] = "yourpassword"`
5. Modify the env var for the [subprocess only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453495/5692012)