# Automating input in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that runs a few psql commands. Every time a command is ran it prompts for user password. I'd like to make the script input the password automatically so I'd only need to run the script and not need to input anything.
I am aware that I can do this for psql

```bash
PGPASSWORD=root psql -h localhost -d $db_name -U root -c
```

but I'd like to know how to automate input in general/

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127/how-do-i-specify-a-password-to-psql-non-interactively

Answer (score 0):

You can export the PGPASSWORD as below:

1. `export PGPASSWORD=root`
2. `psql -h localhost -d $db_name -U root -c`